# VBA Trend returned value

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, trend

I have two array defined inside of VBA, and I want to find by linear interpolation points in between based on known values.

```
Sub example()
Dim boundpoint(1 To 2) As Integer
Dim boundeleva(1 To 2) As Double
Dim totELEV as Integer
ReDim plvl(201) as Double
Dim out As Variant
totELEV = 12
boundeleva(1) = -61.90
boundeleva(2) = -260.25
boundpoint(1) = 1
boundpoint(2) = 201

    For i = 1 to totELEV
        out = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(boundPoint,boundEleva,ELEV(i),True)
        plvl(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(out,0)
    Next i

End Sub
```

But of course it is not working due to mismatch. If I understand it right, "trend" is returning an array for each ELEV(i).
Now I just want the returned value to be a Double that can be rounded up to the closest Integer.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: What is ELEV? Can you write `Option Explicit` on the top of your sub, debug it in the VB Editor and paste the fixed code?

Comment: True, I forgot to include that. ELEV it is just an array with doubles. But I found that the best solution was to code my own function for interpolation instead of bothering with Trend.

Comment: `Trend` doesn't do interpolation at all -- it does regression. Unless the input values are perfectly collinear, the results wouldn't be the same. If you do want piecewise linear interpolation, then it is probably best to write your own. On the other hand, if linear regression is what you want, it is probably best to figure out how to use `trend` since Excel's built-in function is probably bit more numerically stable and faster (since it runs compiled C/C++) than one you would get if you roll your own in VBA.